# What is the term used when an object stops smoothly when scroll finished?

Tags: phrase-request, american-english

What is the term used when an object stops smoothly when scroll finished? For example when you rotate the days of calendar in smartphone its stops somewhere or when you play roulette when you rotate it and then stops somewhere. What is the term in general and also in developing world ?

Comment: It *stops spinning*? It *stopped at a certain value*?

Comment: yes stopped at a certain value, i want the term for the effect of stoping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say:

> It landed on 'red 15'

*it* refers to the pointer to the position on the roulette wheel pointing to "red 15" (in your example), or

> It stopped on 'May 20'

*it* refers to the action, and the item finally displayed when scrolling through views is "May 20" (in your smartphone example).